# Automatically resolve conflict at specific lines using find/replace

Tags: git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree, merge-conflict-resolution, beyondcompare4

There was some kind of misunderstanding which resulted in conflict in 100+ files. The conflict is very easy to resolve though. One set of files has:

```
// In .h files
virtual bool exec();
// in cpp files:
bool SomeClassName::exec() {
```

And the other set has:

```
// In .h files
virtual bool work();
// in cpp files:
bool SomeClassName::work() {
```

I would like to resolve this automatically. Doing it manually would take two hours or more. How can I find and replace `work()` to `exec()`? Apart from git, I also can use SourceTree and BeyondCompare if it can help my situation.

Note that additional conflict may need manual resolution after this is resolved, so the files must not be automatically marked as resolved.

Comment: and you want to resolve them like...?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it makes sense to make some changes before actual merge. For example, in this case the method rename could be done before by IDE's "refactoring" functionality.

If merging is already in progress, it can be aborted by `git merge --abort` (**make sure you have saved resolved files**), it will reset repository to the version before merging.

Comment: Please use comments to ask for details. And no, unfortunately I was in about 20% of merging process already, so using IDE for mass renaming wouldn't work.